# Using toFixed to get a decimal number for a number field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, numbers, decimal

I have this field

```
<input type="number" name="amount" step="0.01" ng-model="amount" />
```

`$scope.amount` is a variable with the value in it which is a string so I do this:

```
$scope.amount = parseInt($scope.amount).toFixed(2);
```

This does return the value of let's say `0.00` but it is in a string but it won't populate the field as it is only a number field and `toFixed();` is returning a string even though I still parsed it.

What is a way around this?

Comment: Do you want to store the variable as a number, isn't it?

Comment: `type="number"` doesn't support float number. You need to change to `type="text"`.

Comment: [<input type="number">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) doesn't have a format property, so it will always remove the unnecessary decimal places. (well, if you TYPE the number it will keep the zeros, but not if you set the number via code)

Answer (score 0):

use parseFloat
$scope.amount = parseFloat(parseInt($scope.amount).toFixed(2));

toFixed() converts the number to string
check here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Comment: This is just returning the value of 0.

Comment: Ok so this is specific to "0.00", parseFloat will give you zero.In that case, you need to change you  to change you input type to text and handle validations by code using onChange method.